# Making a drop down menu containing radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

So here is the concept I am wanting to achieve:
[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqmO1.jpg)

For those who are unable to view the image, I have a drop-down menu (titled "Presets") containing a list of radio buttons each representing a different preset where upon hovering/selecting on a radio button, the preset corresponding with that radio button is previewed (on hovering over the button) and implemented (on selecting the radio button) on a different div element.

```
<nav id="topNav">
<ul style="list-style: none;">
<li>
  <a href="#" title="Nav Link 2">presets</a>
  <ul style="list-style: none;">
    <li><input type="radio" class="rb" id="pr1" name="preset" value="1" checked="checked">Preset 1</li>
    <li><input type="radio" class="rb" id="pr2" name="preset" value="2">Preset 2</li>
    <li><input type="radio" class="rb" id="pr3" name="preset" value="3">Preset 3</li>
    <li><input type="radio" class="rb" id="pr4" name="preset" value="4">Preset 4</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

```
      <div id="a"></div>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/JppP5/24/) is my attempt at executing this. There are a few things that I am having trouble troubleshooting (so I need troubleshooting for myself before I can troubleshoot my problems):

1. The menu seems to drop down by default everytime I refresh the page. Is there a way I can have the menu stay compacted upon refreshing?
2. From my fiddle, you will have noticed on my CSS that I am trying to give my radio buttons hover characteristics (as a way of previewing their presents on the div element) but to no avail. I figure I will need to use scripts for that, right? Specifically, when the mouse cursor hovers over a preset, the div element will momentarily express the details of that preset (in this case, a different color) and when the preset is selected, the div element will change its current color to that of the selected preset.
3. I plan on expanding on this by having the user select a preset for the div element and send the form to save it on a database. Given the functionalities I want, will I have trouble pulling this off in terms of browser compatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can set `display:none` on the `ul` element you're using as the dropdown.
2. Most practical approach for this would be to add `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event listeners to each of the `li` items. On `mouseenter` you set the preview div's color to the one associated with `li` element on which the event took place. On `mouseleave` you would set it back to the original color.
3. Shouldn't be a problem for most browsers.

Here's a modified version of your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JppP5/25/) demonstrating the desired behavior.

Comment: Nice. Would I also have to use jquery or jscript to implement a preset? So basically when a present button is pressed (as opposed to just hovered) I want the div element to replace its current color with the one belonging to the preset in question.

Comment: It's not impossible to do with CSS, but my preference would be to add a `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` using JavaScript. Using jQuery is not necessary but it does help with browser compatibility.

Comment: added a fiddle to demonstrate a possible approach

Comment: Ah, I think there is a slight misunderstanding. Great thanks for your demonstration, but I was referring to being able to permanently set the color change when the button is pressed (so when I press the button for green, the box permanently stays green).

Comment: Thats simpler. Simply use a click event instead of mouseenter.